# How can i create a Thread that running on background on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, background

I have a Thread with open socket connection in a activity, I like to use the thread globaly so that I can get data from thread in other Activities. Somethink like running on the background...

Does anyone have a solution or examples for me?

Thank u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [**Service**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

or try this code

```
void runInBackground() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // DO your work here
                    // get the data
                    if (activity_is_not_in_background) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //uddate UI
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    runInBackground();
                }
            });
        }
```

And the third method using Async Task-- [**Understanding AsyncTask**](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

Comment: AsyncsTask could be a great option, if you want to do some heavy process in background

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple activities to have access to this thread then I would combine Vaibs_cool's sample of running a thread (it's just a normal Thread, nothing Android specific about it) and then...

extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) (make an entry for it in the Manifest) and put that Thread in there.

That way all your activities can talk to it.

Comment: Do i need call the class that extend Application for the first time or its starting automaticaly?

Comment: No, as long as you put it in the Manifest it's actually the first thing that starts and the last thing that's cleaned up in your app. It's guaranteed to be there as long as any Activity exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

If you want to open socket and make it opened even after Activity close  use `Service`

On other hand if you want to open socket during Activity is running and close on Activity close then use `AsyncTask`

You can find example how to use `AsyncTask` <kbd>[here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)</kbd>

From Docs:

> **Network** operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI. The **AsyncTask** class provides one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.